# Using Uber Driver API to know when pickups are going to happen?

Tags: uber-api, lyft-api

Is there a way to use the Uber Driver API to be notified when the driver is a certain distance away from doing a pickup?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not one of the endpoints on the Uber driver API. The existing endpoints are profile, payments, & trips: https://developer.uber.com/docs/drivers/introduction

Real time availability / status of a driver is not a current existing driver API endpoint.